# MPR I suppose somehow I found a way to make a super hacker angry with me

Tags: attack-prevention

I suppose somehow I found a way to make a super hacker angry with me.
I've lost three cellphones.
It might have all started with the iPhone 4 getting locked then both androids to simlock.
And I'm at three laptops to this ignorant Windows mpr rewriting boot that starts as soon as I turn on the screen.

My question is, how do I rewrite a boot so it stops rewriting.

Comment: I think you mean MBR instead of MPR? With respect to the phones, maybe someone in your house or at work is messing with them when you leave them unattended?

Comment: There's a lot of odd details in this question. What are you really asking?

Answer (score 1):

- Scan the infected machine using a virus scanner on a bootable dvd/usb stick (http://www.google.com/search?q=live+image+virus+scan) download and burn it via a not infected device.
- If the virus scan does not allow you to repair the MBR you can use the procedure outlined in https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/927392/en-us for Windows 7 and Vista, probably Windows 8 has a similar procedure, for Liunx systems you can use grub (http://www.google.com/search?q=grub+repair+boot+sector).
- Finally you can protect your MBR and boot sector by disallowing modifications to it via the BIOS.